# How to convert Date format like this Fri Apr 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) to 2020-04-20T00:00:00.000Z in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I have a Date format like this `"Fri Apr 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"`

I want to convert that above format to this format `2020-04-20T00:00:00.000Z`

Actually I tried this `JSON.stringify(new Date("Fri Apr 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"))` while using this am getting the output one day before `2020-04-19T18:30:00.000Z`

so please anyone help me to convert this date format  `"Fri Apr 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"` like this `2020-04-20T00:00:00.000Z`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Fri Apr 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) and 2020-04-19T18:30:00.000Z are the same moment in time, they just use different offsets. 2020-04-20T00:00:00.000Z is Fri Apr 20 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your date seems to be a standard string representation of `new Date()`, you can get the desired format by using `new Date().toISOString()`

```js
console.log(new Date().toString())
console.log(new Date().toISOString())

// To create it from string
const dateStr = "Fri Apr 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
console.log(new Date(dateStr).toISOString())
```

Comment: am getting one day before like this 2020-04-19T18:30:00.000Z

Comment: I want the output like this bro 2020-04-20T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: JS date is based on the timezone of your computer, if you want the string like above, you can take the date from date object, and add time string `00:00:00` manually. Or  you can use a library like moment.js

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava—the timezone settings of the host are irrelevant for this question. "Fri Apr 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" has a timezone offset, it will be used to determine the equivalent UTC time when it's parsed. It actually represents 2020-04-19T18:30:00.000Z, which is what *toISOString* returns.

Comment: @RobG Ok I get it, hopefully you can provide the correct solution

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava—your answer is fine, I was commenting on your comment. :-)

Comment: @RobG There's no way to add the offset to get the required time?

Comment: That requires parsing the original string and specifically ignoring the offset. Not difficult (3 or 4 lines of code), but "[*how to parse a date*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+parse+a+date)" has been asked a million times before. :-)

Comment: @RobG Yes I was thinking something of that sort

Comment: Is there any way to convert vice versa like normal string 5pm into 2022-04-20T17:00:00.000Z format?

Answer (score 1):

Anurag Srivastava's answer shows how you *should* parse the string and format it in the required format (given that the string is in one of the two formats supported by ECMA-262 and considering [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)).

Note that "Fri Apr 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" is the same instant in time as "2020-04-19T18:30:00.000Z". The first string is offset from UTC by 5 hr 30 min, so the equivalent UTC time is 5 hr 30 min earlier, which means the date is the previous day.

You haven't given a reason why you want to treat it as UTC and not consider the offset, so I don't think you should.

However, if you do have a good reason to parse it as UTC and ignore the supplied offset, then you can either:

1. Modify the input string to set the offset as +0 and parse it using the built–in parser
2. Parse the string yourself and treat it as UTC

```js
let s = "Fri Apr 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";

// #1 Modify the input string, setting the offset to +0
let d = new Date(s.replace(/GMT.*$/,'GMT+0000')).toISOString();

console.log(d.toISOString());

// #2 Bespoke parser
function parseAsUTC(s) {
  let months = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun',
                'jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];
  let b = s.split(/\W/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[3], months.indexOf(b[1].toLowerCase()),
                           b[2], b[4], b[5], b[6]));
}

console.log(parseAsUTC(s).toISOString());
```